# Can a SMPS LED driver glow 6 Watt LED bulb and same Driver is able to glow 0.5 Watt LED?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply

[image]

LED : 150mA * 3.3v =0.5 Watt
6 Watt LED (0.5 Watt* 12) : Which one is best method to arrange LEDs Parallel or Series.
At a time only one LED will glow, Either 6 watt LED or 0.5 Watt LED.

---

[image]

Please give answer as per this Pix

Answer (score 1):

In principle, yes.  But the devil's in the detail.  12 LEDs in series needs 12 times the voltage to drive them.  As Andy aka points out, you also need to include current limiting in your design.  You could instead put 12 LEDs in parallel, with separate current limiting for each.

You need to check the voltage and current capabilities of your power supply, and the voltage and current handling capabilities of your switching transistors.

Answer (score 0):

> Which one is best method to arrange LEDs Parallel or Series

Always put LEDs in series as a golden rule. Putting them in parallel can mean that one LED hogs all the current, destroys itself then the next one will hog all the current and destroy itself etc..

> At a time only one LED will glow, Either 6 watt LED or 0.5 Watt LED.

I have no idea what this means.

Comment: Please visit given image

Comment: There are two LEDs, LED1 and LED2. LED1 is 6 watt and LED2 is 0.5 Watt. LED1 and LED2 controlled by a Micro controller, So only one LED will glow at a time, Either LED1or LED2.

Comment: @B.Sharma the image has no bearing on your question as far as I can tell. However it's clear that you haven't considered how the current into the LEDs are controlled (usually a resistor).

Comment: 150mA current for LED

Comment: How is that current limited to 150mA?

Comment: I'll arrange 12 LED in series and LED requires 150mA current

Comment: How do you plan to limit the current to 150mA - an LED will take enough current to destroy itself if you don't get the voltage absolutely spot-on. What circuit mechanism are you going to use to protect the LEDs from over-current when the voltage is a little bit too high.